# How to use a static function of a class passed as a parameter

Tags: typescript, class, types

Basically, I need to use a static function of a class passed as a parameter:

EDIT:

### I didn't explain myself properly, I hope you can understand me with this example.

> Minimal Reproducible Example.

```
const TABLES = {
  bike: [],
  car: []
};

class Vehicles {
  static table = "";
  static getAll<T extends Vehicles>(): T[] {
    return TABLES[this.table];
  }
}

class Bike extends Vehicles {
  static table = "bike";
}

class Car extends Vehicles {
  static table = "car";
}

function getVehicleByClass<T extends Vehicles>(Vehicle: typeof T) { // 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
  Vehicle.getAll();
}

getVehicleByClass<Car>(Car);
```

Comment: I've tried to help below, but a more complete (and runnable) [mcve] would help clarify the question, and may lead to a better solution.

Comment: Just a side note: There's no `await` anywhere in your `createAssociations`. Unless it uses `await`, there's no reason for it to be `async`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your answer! I updated my question so you can understand me properly.
Async was not necessary by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer

...after the edit to the question.

The generic type should extend `typeof Vehicles` rather than `Vehicles`:

```
function getVehicleByClass<T extends typeof Vehicles>(Vehicle: T) {
  Vehicle.getAll();
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgQQEIBkCiBlGBeGBvAKBhgCMBLAawFMAuGAbQF0AaImYAQwCc6mCBfANwECwADYcIEGADUqACzLiq0wsWgcoSmFA4kxVHDABEx4et1bgMAOZUoCMWIA8cGFQAeUKmAAm0uUVlCAA%20AAoASjo4Jnw2Yi57AFcuMHhkdAx6KEUIADpdfSpGcxh%20ARFxSWkkSkNPbz8AhSUDVTYNKx09AyNjcmozCtEJKRgAYW53Lx9-WRbguItNbULe3GNOLiHyggAzJLBgLXBbe0DWqiQAT3HRiFdpxrmoa4AHKhA9%20aC28IvlNEIksfpc8nYHE5IsJdhCAQYbndqmFJlwIoIgA)

That said, I might give myself a type for `typeof Vehicles`:

```
type VehiclesType = typeof Vehicles;
```

Then:

```
function getVehicleByClass<T extends VehiclesType>(Vehicle: T) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
  Vehicle.getAll();
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=22&ssc=130&pln=22&pc=65#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKgQQEIBkCiBlGBeGBvAKBhgCMBLAawFMAuGAbQF0AaImYAQwCc6mCBfANwECwADYcIEGADUqACzLiq0wsWgcoSmFA4kxVHDABEx4et1bgMAOZUoCMWIA8cGFQAeUKmAAm0uUVlCAA%20AAoASjo4Jnw2Yi57AFcuMHhkdAx6KEUIADpdfSpGcxh%20AQIoAE8AB0NApQMIOFrDXGq6kAAzWQVGlWFRCSkYJEpDT28-AL7guItNbUKDI2NyajMKoclpAGFudy8ff16gpvmYDSsdPRXcY04uTfKCLqSwYC1wW3sG5SQqrthhBXIcpic-k0WnVwpDaPAIhc4Xk7A4nJFhC9UXCAUCdmF9lwIoIgA)

...just because I think better in smaller pieces. :-D

### Original answer

*(I'm only leaving this because you said it was useful for some other stuff you were working...)*

What you have should work, I suspect the real problem here is that you don't have typings for `Object.values` (added in ES2017). You'll want to check your tsconfig.json to make sure your `lib` option is ES2017 or higher.

If you have the typings for `Object.values`, [this works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEAUBsEME8HMBOB7ArgOwCagJYGdQBbfPHdeUAAwDdpJUBTPSgGlAElQloAjHh7ABcAFvlCYGAMzI5BOZOgBQIUMkm5BoSSkJVIOHsCYAmAAwBGAOwA6ZDwBWDAMaDrma4ObXFZQQ0SS0E4MoADyDs6CAMIKeIKIqC7IiKAA3oqgmaDAAFQ5GVmgOaAASgyCqIjoBNDooNCIiHCq6rT0TC2gIiEM6KiE-ryQIQAOKCP+ch1q9XV2ji4FWcUAAiMN0LrIYREuXcLQmk4KgtBkBN2gY8gTiFM1WETlwsiYeNagACqiBE61oPxZqpdpoRIdQLA0KAnIgGIcBKoUv8GAAPfBycigAAiyCc-V6mnCC00AFlXgxIKAABRY0IkgCUwOJ3kKRWAS1AbUYeAAPJ8AHxU5AALjSoAA2nhRXFEGR4ABdUWfUAAX1AAB9QABBRpwAAyOAA1gw+fz6UrxfKANyKFWKRROGB4AhkiSU9KFOKHHBOerO3E4eFUwjkyBSsXi42waXxOWKrqwCYzV0U1XmiNRmOy8jxwSJhjJ0OqtIcwqwipVMWSZAi0Apykqm2FO12x3QZ110PGUCovxYF1F9Ktp0Dt0AZh7KL7b07bpLdsU7dg6F9kgwLnkdRhcL8Wv9TkDcliwdD4dSEszoBlcdFeaT6nradF4B0+BN1GQOEw-JLmSJkWsLkmBPN08Hpaxq0QABRIJhBA1MAF4fw9LIcHUeDIGsds8ADeFGRQwoQzdLD90PBgMLApssjtTIVXpG0VSAA):

```
class Model {
    static associate(models: { [key: string]: typeof Model }): { [key: string]: typeof Model } {
        return { foo: Model };
    }
}
class Model2 extends Model {
}
class Model3 extends Model {
}

async function createAssociations(models: { [key: string]: typeof Model }): Promise<void> {
  Object.values(models).forEach(model => {
    if (model.associate) {
      model.associate(models);
    }
  });
}
```

...though I think I'd use a type for that `{[key: string]: typeof Model}` type since you use it in multiple places:

```
type ModelValuesObject = { [key: string]: typeof Model };
```

Then:

```
class Model {
    static associate(models: ModelValuesObject): ModelValuesObject {
        return { foo: Model };
    }
}
class Model2 extends Model {
}
class Model3 extends Model {
}

async function createAssociations(models: ModelValuesObject): Promise<void> {
  Object.values(models).forEach(model => {
    if (model.associate) {
      model.associate(models);
    }
  });
}
```

---

If you want the **minimum** change, you can type the `model` parameter of your `forEach` callback:

```
Object.values(models).forEach((model: typeof Model) =>
```

That will allow you to use the `static` method on the classes in `model`'s values.

But TypeScript can infer it. Here I've taken `{[key: string]: typeof Model}` and giving it a handy name so we can reuse it:

```
type ModelValuesObject = { [key: string]: typeof Model };
```

Then it's:

```
class Model {
    static associate(models: ModelValuesObject): ModelValuesObject {
        return { foo: Model };
    }
}
class Model2 extends Model {
}
class Model3 extends Model {
}

async function createAssociations(models: ModelValuesObject): Promise<void> {
  Object.values(models).forEach(model => {
    if (model.associate) {
      model.associate(models);
    }
  });
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEAUBsEME8HMBOB7ArgOwCagJYGdQBbfPHdeUAAwDdpJUBTPSgGlAElQloAjHh7ABcAFvlCYGAMzI5BOZOgBQIUMkm5BoSSkJVIOHsCYAmAAwBGAOwA6ZDwBWDAMaDrma4ObXFZQQ0SS0E4MoADyDs6CAMIKeIKIqC7IiKAA3oqgmaDAAFQ5GVmgOaAASgyCqIjoBNDooNCIiHCq6rT0TC2gIiEM6KiE-ryQIQAOKCP+ch1q9XV2ji4FWcUAAiMN0LrIYREuXcLQmk4KgtBkBN2gY8gTiFM1WETlwsiYeNagACqiBE61oPxZqpdpoRIdQLA0KAnIgGIcBKoUv8GAAPfBycigAAiyCc-V6mnCC00AFlXgxIKAABRY0IkgCUwOJ3kKRWAS1AbUYeAAPJ8AHxU5AALjSoAA2nhRXFEGR4ABdUWfUAAX1AAB9QABBRpwAAyOAA1gw+fz6UrxfKANyKFWKZRgT7baDUZA4bCwiaHOX7fCKQSwCagMkSSAANTo3KJkVAAF4xeLjbBpfE5YquoGGDMQxTVTbFE4YHgCDnKelCnFvU56sXcTh4VTCOTIFLg82I+08NGXOa26GO1GQWkOYVYRUqmLJMgRX3cyqbYU7XbC9Bi7PIMZQKi-FgS83h8ui3vQwBmLcondvdcH+2r2DoauSDAueR1GFwvxa2tOetyWKN5tW1LAcmG7QRe3AHR8BNV13X5YdMjA6wuSYADQzwelrCnRAAFEgmENDc1jeDyyyHB1EIyBrFXPA63hRlSMKJtQ2o79fwYSiMIXLI7UyFV6RtFUgA)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It worked like a charm in other examples, however, in that case, `.associate` was not declared in the class Model. 

I was migrating this from JavaScript to TypeScript, and I used to declared the property in other file for some classes. I just had to extend the class and set `.associate` as a new function, however I am facing this new problem (the one shown in the edited question).

Comment: This problem had haunted me a couple of projects, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Zeswen - No worries! I just realized that the type I added isn't necessary (I might use it anyway, but it isn't necessary). It can be just `function getVehicleByClass<T extends typeof Vehicles>(Vehicle: T)`.

Comment: @Zeswen - BTW, your question increased my understanding of TypeScript, so...thank **you**! :-)